# FreeRADIUS doesn't receive any requests

Tags: freeradius, radius

I configured FreeRadius to use MySQL and everything was working until a while ago, when some teammates complained they cannot authenticate to the server.

So I started FreeRadius again in debug mode and I tried with the `radtest testing password 127.0.0.1 0 testing123` classic testing, but I receive `No reply from server for ID 241 socket 3`.

Actually it seems that the server doesn't receive anything since in the log I just can see Ready to process requests message, when I run the radtest.

From the output of the debug mode, it seems Free Radius is listening

```
radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####
listen {
        type = "auth"
        ipaddr = *
        port = 1813
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "acct"
        ipaddr = *
        port = 1814
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "auth"
        ipv6addr = ::
        port = 1813
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "acct"
        ipv6addr = ::
        port = 1814
   limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
        type = "auth"
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        port = 18120
}
Listening on auth address * port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on acct address * port 1814 bound to server default
Listening on auth address :: port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on acct address :: port 1814 bound to server default
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel
Listening on proxy address * port 36889
Listening on proxy address :: port 48860
```

and also the client configuration seems correct to me

```
client localhost {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        proto = *
        secret = testing123
#       shortname = localhost
        nas_type         = other        # localhost isn't usually a NAS...        
        limit {
                
                max_connections = 16
                lifetime = 0
                idle_timeout = 30
        }
}
```

Can you help me to debug why it doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You have changed the ports in the configuration. Auth should be on port 1812, and acct on 1813, not 1813 and 1814 as you currently have.

Comment: The ports were indeed wrong, since we had a special configuration and not using standard ports. But instead of changing ports, I decided to send the requests on that ports with rad test. I post here the command in case could be useful for someone `radtest user testing 127.0.0.1:1813 0 testing123`